# Streams collect vs. map collect

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There are a few methods in `Stream` especially when dealing with numerical values which can be written this way or another. (The same question would apply for `average()`)

So which method is preferable:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics result;

result = stream()
        .collect( Collectors.summarizingDouble( weighter::weight ) );
```

vs.

```
result = stream()
        .mapToDouble( weighter::weight )
        .summaryStatistics();
```

and why?

(As I see it, the first one has the advantage of "visiting" each element only once, while the second one has cleaner semantics but is visiting each element at least twice. But is this even important/correct?)

Comment: I think that there is no preffered way, both are correct it depends what do you want to achieve...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance wise, it seems that the second approach (map then summarize) is faster than the first approach (using the collector):

```
Benchmark                         (n)  Mode  Samples     Score     Error  Units
c.a.p.SO26775395.collector         10  avgt       10     0.110 ±   0.004  us/op
c.a.p.SO26775395.collector       1000  avgt       10     9.134 ±   0.310  us/op
c.a.p.SO26775395.collector    1000000  avgt       10  9091.649 ± 274.113  us/op
c.a.p.SO26775395.summary           10  avgt       10     0.110 ±   0.003  us/op
c.a.p.SO26775395.summary         1000  avgt       10     5.593 ±   0.234  us/op
c.a.p.SO26775395.summary      1000000  avgt       10  5598.776 ± 153.314  us/op
```

Benchmark code:

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public class SO26775395 {

  @Param({"10", "1000", "1000000"}) int n;
  List<Weighter> weights;

  @Setup public void setup() {
    weights = new Random().doubles(n)
            .mapToObj(Weighter::new)
            .collect(toList());
  }

  @Benchmark public DoubleSummaryStatistics collector() {
    return weights.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Weighter::w));
  }

  @Benchmark public DoubleSummaryStatistics summary() {
    return weights.stream().mapToDouble(Weighter::w).summaryStatistics();
  }

  public static class Weighter {
    private final double w;
    public Weighter(double w) { this.w = w; }
    public double w() { return w; }
  }

}
```

Comment: so the second one is cleaner *AND* faster. I wonder why. The benchmark looks interesting. What did you use for that?

Answer (score 1):

Many predefined [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) might seem redundant since they represent operations that are directly accessible on a Stream. However, they make sense when you start to compose Collectors. For example:

```
Map<Department, DoubleSummaryStatistics> statsByDept = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,
                                   Collectors.summarizingDouble(Employee::getSalary)));
```

Answer (score -2):

summaryStatistics() gives you more information but its performance may not be the desired, depends on what you want to get as output...

Comment: No. They both give the same result.